# How to search for text in an array of varchar field in Presto?

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-like, presto

A field is defined to be `array(varchar)` in modeanlyatic.

I want to search for records with field contains a certain text pattern, says `'ABCD'`.

If I run this SQL:

```
select * from data_table 
where top_results like '%ABCD%'
```

It throws this error:

> Query failed (#20190730_021145_23663_dn9fj): line 2:7: Left side of
>   LIKE expression must evaluate to a varchar (actual: array(varchar)

What is the correct syntax to detect the presence of a certain string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [filter(array(T), function(T, boolean)) -> array(T)](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/array.html)

it returns array containing elements for which function returns true. Use cardinality function to check if array is not empty:

```
SELECT cardinality(filter(ARRAY ['123ABCD456', 'DQF', 'ABCD', 'ABC'], x -> x like '%ABCD%'))>0 ;
```

Returns

```
true
```

Check another value:

```
SELECT cardinality(filter(ARRAY ['123ABCD456', 'DQF', 'ABCD', 'ABC'], x -> x like '%XXX%'))>0 ;
```

Returns

```
false
```

Hope you got the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Convert it to a json string and then search the string

`json_format(cast(top_results as JSON))`

```
select * from data_table 
where json_format(cast(top_results as JSON)) like '%ABCD%'
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it fixes the problem, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Comment: This is about as simple as it gets but point noted.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `any_match` for that:

```
SELECT *
FROM data_table 
WHERE any_match(top_results, s -> s like '%ABCD%')
```